# Define fields which the LIVE query in orientdb should return

Tags: sql, node.js, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I'm currently working with LIVE queries in OrientDB. Is it possible to decide which fields a 'live-update, live-insert or live-delete' event will return?

I tried a live query like this:

```
LIVE SELECT username, description FROM User
```

But it returns the whole node (record). I'm working with the NodeJS library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for now it's not possible. Live queries yields the entire record involved in the live query